# Configuring keycloak as IDP in another keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to configure a keycloak as an IDP in another keycloak. In my test setup there are 2 keycloak containers - keycloak-1 and keycloak-2.

In keycloak-1, I have created an openid client called idp-client. The configuration exported as JSON is shown below,

```
{
    "clientId": "idp-client",
    "surrogateAuthRequired": false,
    "enabled": true,
    "alwaysDisplayInConsole": false,
    "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
    "redirectUris": [
        "http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/master/broker/oidc/endpoint"
    ],
    "webOrigins": [],
    "notBefore": 0,
    "bearerOnly": false,
    "consentRequired": false,
    "standardFlowEnabled": true,
    "implicitFlowEnabled": false,
    "directAccessGrantsEnabled": true,
    "serviceAccountsEnabled": false,
    "publicClient": false,
    "frontchannelLogout": false,
    "protocol": "openid-connect",
    "attributes": {
        "saml.assertion.signature": "false",
        "saml.force.post.binding": "false",
        "saml.multivalued.roles": "false",
        "saml.encrypt": "false",
        "saml.server.signature": "false",
        "saml.server.signature.keyinfo.ext": "false",
        "exclude.session.state.from.auth.response": "false",
        "saml_force_name_id_format": "false",
        "saml.client.signature": "false",
        "tls.client.certificate.bound.access.tokens": "false",
        "saml.authnstatement": "false",
        "display.on.consent.screen": "false",
        "saml.onetimeuse.condition": "false"
    },
    "authenticationFlowBindingOverrides": {},
    "fullScopeAllowed": true,
    "nodeReRegistrationTimeout": -1,
    "defaultClientScopes": [
        "web-origins",
        "role_list",
        "profile",
        "roles",
        "email"
    ],
    "optionalClientScopes": [
        "address",
        "phone",
        "offline_access",
        "microprofile-jwt"
    ],
    "access": {
        "view": true,
        "configure": true,
        "manage": true
    }
}
```

In keycloak-2, I have added keycloak-1 as an identity provider. I have attached the images of the configuration for reference.

[image: Keycloak 2 IDP configuration - Image 1]
[image: Keycloak 2 IDP configuration - Image 2]

Now when I try to login to keycloak-2 using keycloak-1's user, after successful login, I am redirected to keycloak-2's but to an error page, its showing "Unexpected error when authenticating with identity provider"

[image: Keycloak 2 login screen]
[image: Login error message]

Stacktrace in the keycloak-2's terminal is as below,

```
keycloak2_1  | 08:21:17,079 TRACE [org.keycloak.events] (default task-10) type=CODE_TO_TOKEN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=idp-client, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_client_credentials, grant_type=authorization_code, requestUri=http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token, cookies=[]

...

...

keycloak2_1  | 08:21:17,081 TRACE [org.keycloak.events] (default task-12) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=172.21.0.1, error=identity_provider_login_failure, requestUri=http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/master/broker/oidc/endpoint?state=MOz5_i2-SpoSLRtS4IWkXtUBsSzGciBysUrdYq8gGy0.k0e5WlQElRw.security-admin-console&session_state=1cc90330-cf3c-45c3-a44e-53fc71b17bb1&code=be12828b-3408-4822-b275-31afeb1c0405.1cc90330-cf3c-45c3-a44e-53fc71b17bb1.eb068c43-9f4e-45b7-b2e8-ac346f139141, cookies=[KEYCLOAK_SESSION_LEGACY=master/ce30941f-407f-4344-9019-58d2f26ea832/1cc90330-cf3c-45c3-a44e-53fc71b17bb1, PrivacyPolicy=accepted, KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY_LEGACY=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICIxNjgzNzMzNi1mMTA3LTRiMTktODk1Yi0wNWJmZDliZGIzYTUifQ.eyJleHAiOjE2MDk3ODQ0NzcsImlhdCI6MTYwOTc0ODQ3NywianRpIjoiNTQ3YmRlZGQtOGQyYy00MTJkLWJhMzYtZjkyNzAwNjlhYzQxIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL2F1dGgvcmVhbG1zL21hc3RlciIsInN1YiI6ImNlMzA5NDFmLTQwN2YtNDM0NC05MDE5LTU4ZDJmMjZlYTgzMiIsInR5cCI6IlNlcmlhbGl6ZWQtSUQiLCJzZXNzaW9uX3N0YXRlIjoiMWNjOTAzMzAtY2YzYy00NWMzLWE0NGUtNTNmYzcxYjE3YmIxIiwic3RhdGVfY2hlY2tlciI6IkZFT3psWkRScXhqREVVOGV6MFd6MU5menZGYU1jNHRzV1J4TnlrNUc5NDQifQ.YeBB6vJYZ9Z4IUXY2-og17EMRodUdeqTBTQ31pY3P1s, AUTH_SESSION_ID_LEGACY=1cc90330-cf3c-45c3-a44e-53fc71b17bb1.4c93e8da0ca1]
```

In keycloak-1, the user is logged in i.e. a session is shown for idp-client.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned issue was rectified once the SSL was enabled.

Comment: Can you add the steps explicitly might be useful for other people as well